# Converting Object to Array using ES6 features

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Given a javascript object, how can I convert it to an array in ECMAScript-6 ?

For example, given:

```
 var inputObj = {a:'foo', b:[1,2,3], c:null, z:55};
```

The expected output would be:

```
 ['foo', [1,2,3], null, 55]
```

The order of the elements in the result is not important to me.

Comment: I didn't get if you have an answer, for what you are looking here?

Comment: @Mritunjay A blog post, perhaps..

Comment: No, its fine to do that. It is a decent question and a decent answer.  Though I expected it could be added as an answer for a similar question except they don't seem to be es6 specific.

Comment: I put a jsperf up here: http://jsperf.com/objects-to-array/2

Comment: use Object.values(inputObj)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

just use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```
Object.values(inputObj); // => ['foo', [1,2,3], null, 55]
```

Comment: Effortless and elegant, but it's esnext feature so you definitely need to look for browser support

Comment: @Samiullah everyone now is using babel! Especially if you are using ES6 and cares about browsers compatibility

Answer (score 124):

Use (ES5) [`Array::map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions) (for short syntax only, not functionality):

```
let arr = Object.keys(obj).map((k) => obj[k])
```

---

True ES6 style would be to write a generator, and convert that iterable into an array:

```
function* values(obj) {
    for (let prop of Object.keys(obj)) // own properties, you might use
                                       // for (let prop in obj)
        yield obj[prop];
}
let arr = Array.from(values(obj));
```

Regrettably, no [object iterator](http://esdiscuss.org/topic/es6-iteration-over-object-values) has made it into the ES6 natives.

Comment: This method is about 85 times (yes times, not percent) slower than the old school 'for in' method on this test case.  Would this change significantly over larger data sets?

Comment: How did you execute ES6? What test data did you use, have you tried different sizes? Yes, `map` is known to be a bit slower than loops.

Comment: Firefox has it already enabled,  Chrome needs chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony.  It runs, but in current implementations it is slow as molasses.  I am guessing the reason the object iterators were omitted is that existing JIT compilers can already recognize these patterns in the old school methods.

Comment: it's probably not `map` that is the slow part, the slow part is probably the building of a throwaway array done by `Object.keys`. If you had a generator func that didn't use `Object.keys` then I'd expect it would be much closer in speed to `for in`.

Comment: @andy: Taking a look again, there is `Reflect.enumerate(obj)` that does exactly this. But I have no idea whether it would be faster, especially since it doesn't seem to be implemented anywhere yet. Btw, `Object.keys` is actually pretty fast in V8, sometimes faster than `for in`.

Answer (score 13):

### Update August 2020

As a summary, in ES6, there are three (3) variations to convert an Object to an Array as follows:

```
const MyObjects = {   key1: 'value 1',   key2: 'value 2', };

// Method 1: Converts the keys to Array
// --------------------------------------

Object.keys(MyObjects);
// ['key1', 'key2']

// Method 2 Converts the Values to Array
// --------------------------------------

Object.values(MyObjects);
// ['value 1', 'value 2']

// Method 3 Converts both Values and Keys
// --------------------------------------

Object.entries(MyObjects);
// [ ['key1', 'value 1'], ['key2', 'value 2'] ]
```

Converting an Array back to an Object can be done as follows:

```
const array = [  ['one', 1],   ['two', 2], ];

Object.fromEntries(array);

// { one: 1, two: 2 }
```

Answer (score 11):

I like the old school way:

```
var i=0, arr=[];
for (var ob in inputObj)
  arr[i++]=ob;
```

Old school wins the [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/objects-to-array/3) by a large margin, if not the upvotes.  Sometimes new additions are "mis-features."

Comment: What's `obj`, why is `ob` global?

Comment: Yeah, but it's still a global variable. Use `for (let ob i inputObj)`

Comment: @technosaurus I'm sure that your variable `ob` in `for(var ob in inputObj)` is supposed to be a property key.  So inside the loop it should be `arr[i++]=inputObj[ob];`.  This makes it 22% slower than the code you have now.  But it's still much faster than the others in the linked jsperf.

Answer (score 9):

This can be achieved using the [Array Comprehension syntax](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#comprehensions):

```
[for (key of Object.keys(inputObj)) inputObj[key]]
```

Usage example:

```
var inputObj = {a:'foo', b:[1,2,3], c:null, z:55};
var arr = [for (key of Object.keys(inputObj)) inputObj[key]];
console.log(arr);

// prints [ 'foo', [ 1, 2, 3 ], null, 55 ]
```

Comment: @Bergi it doesn't work inside the Array Comprehension syntax (at least with Tracuer)

Comment: Yeah, apparently only iterators are supposed to be used within comprehensions. And there's no `Object` iterator - you are supposed to use `Map`s

Comment: This fails the jsperf on chrome/firefox http://jsperf.com/objects-to-array/2  I don't know how to fix it though.

Comment: Aren't Array Comprehensions ES7?

Comment: They used to be in ES6, and have been removed since. Per https://github.com/tc39/ecma262, it doesn't seem like they will become a part of the ES7.

Answer (score 9):

ES7 way:

```
let obj = { a: "foo", b: "bar", c: 1, d: [1, 2, 3, 4] }

Object.values(obj)

// output --> ['foo', 'bar', 1, [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Please augment this code-only answer with some explanation.

Comment: Sure I could but there's nothing to explain but the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). 

`The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).`

Comment: Dude this is a basic information of the method, this is not the purporse of the topic. It is crystal clear with the example. @Yunnosch

Answer (score 5):

`Array.map` equivalent of [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)'s  arrow function (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more about `Array.map`).

**Edit 2020**: converted to snippet and added an alternative

```js
const obj = {
    a: 'foo',
    b: [1, 2, 3],
    c: null,
    z: 55
  },
  nwArr = Object.keys(obj).map(k => obj[k]),
  // Alternative
  nwArr2 = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj));
  nwArr.a = "bar";
  nwArr2.a = "foobar"
  console.log(`obj.a: ${obj.a}, nwArr.a: ${nwArr.a}, nwArr2.a: ${nwArr2.a}`);
```

Comment: Even more compact version of this `Object.keys(obj).map(k => obj[k])`

Answer (score 0):

```
const address = {
        street: "bew1111",
        city: "err111",
        country: "ind11"
    };
    const address2 = {
        street: "bewscxsd",
        city: "errdc",
        country: "indcdsc"
    };
```

we have two objects here and I am going to use 2 methods for assign both objects into Array

1. `Object.entries()`
2. `Object.keys()`

1st one starts here-----

```
var firstar = Object.entries(address);
```

here I assigned address into `firstar` and when you will run this you will get output like this

```
(3) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
```

2nd one starts here

```
var secstar = Object.keys(address2);
```

here I assigned address2 into `secstar` and when you will run this you will get output like this

```
 (3) ["street", "city", "country"]
```