# How to pass object into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

**Output what I got**

```
{
0:{modifierId: 4, modifierName: 'Garlic',  modifierPrice: 60 }
1:{modifierId: 1, modifierName: 'Tartar ',  modifierPrice: 60}
2:{modifierId: 3, modifierName: 'Herb ',  modifierPrice: 60}
itemId:387
itemName:"BUFFALO WINGS"
itemPrice:500
itemQuantity:0
}
```

I am working on a **point of sale** project using **angular**
The concept is when the user clicks on **itemName** button, it will display it's modifiers in a dialog box. All this data is coming from restful API.
When I click on a **modifier**, it's object is passed into the item's object. In that case, when I call the items to display in cart using ngFor*, it gives an error. Because angular does not allow objects to be passed in ngFor*, it only works with arrays.

**Output I expect**

```
[
0:{modifierId: 4, modifierName: 'Garlic', modifierPrice: 60}
1:{modifierId: 1, modifierName: 'Tartar ',  modifierPrice: 60}
2:{modifierId: 3, modifierName: 'Herb ', modifierPrice: 60}
itemId:387
itemName:"BUFFALO WINGS"
itemPrice:500
itemQuantity:0
*length:3*
]
```

Now what I want is, to pass the modifier's object into an array. So, how can I do that

Comment: Paste your code and click on `{}` icon in the editor to format the code. No need to add backticks in each line: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Also, your expected output is invalid because it expects non-integer keys in an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your object to be casted in array only in the template then you could use the [angular keyvalue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of map | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

Or in your component you can cast your [object into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25218110/5012127) like:

```
let arr = Object.keys(obj).map((k) => obj[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you really want get an object like

```
{
    itemId:387
    itemName:"BUFFALO WINGS"
    itemPrice:500
    itemQuantity:0,
    modifiers:[
       {modifierId: 4, modifierName: 'Garlic', modifierPrice: 60},
       {modifierId: 1, modifierName: 'Tartar ',  modifierPrice: 60},
       {modifierId: 3, modifierName: 'Herb ', modifierPrice: 60}
    ]
}
```

(the "length" are newObject.modifier.length)

```
    newObject={
      itemId:original.itemId,
      itemName:original.itemName,
      itemPrice:original.itemPrice,
      itemQuantity:original.itemQuantity,
      modifiers:Object.keys(original)
            .filter((key:string)=>key.indexOf('item')<0)
            .map((key:string)=>original[key])
 }
```